# How can I preventDefault() on dispatchEvent?

Tags: javascript

I have a submit event handler on a form (to catch people submitting the form with <kbd>enter</kbd>, which sometimes I need to fire manually (triggered by the user clicking on something other than a submit button), via dispatchEvent.

I **don't** want it to actually submit the form though, but once dispatchEvent has been fired it seems I can't cancel it?

```
myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.defaultPrevented); // false
});

myForm.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit', {'detail': 'mydetail'}));
```

In Chrome this still outputs `false`, but the form doesn't submit (the desired behaviour).  In fact even if I remove the preventDefault() line it still doesn't submit?

However, Firefox is a different story, and always submits the form.

How can I change this?

Comment: is it working ok if submitting through the button?

Comment: I don't have a button, I never want the form to actually submit.

Comment: you should try myForm.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit', {'detail': 'mydetail', cancelable: true}));

Comment: That seems to work perfectly, thank you.  For some reason I had it in my head that cancelable was a read-only property that couldn't be set, or I'd have tried it already!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to explicitly code your event with the **cancelable** property to be TRUE and by default, this is not handled.

```
 myForm.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit', {'detail': 'mydetail', cancelable: true}))
```

Comment: You just saved me hours of debug, really thank you @sandyJoshi